# Bulk rescheduling agenda items without altering time of day or DEADLINE?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date

I currently bulk reschedule agenda items using:

```
(setq org-agenda-bulk-custom-functions
  '((?D (lambda () (call-interactively 'org-agenda-date-later)))))
```

This command can be used without a prefix argument to reschedule any marked past items to today. Or it can be used with a prefix argument to specify how many days to change to change the timestamp by.

Another advantage is that it will preserve the time of day of each individual item if present.

The problem is that `org-agenda-date-later` will instead change the DEADLINE timestamp if one is present, instead of the SCHEDULED timestamp.

I've tried using `org-agenda-schedule`, but this command prompts for a new timestamp for each individual item, which is tedious and also prone to deleting or altering the time of day.

Is there a method of bulk rescheduling items to today or by a number of days in one action, which will not alter the deadline or require manually setting each item's timestamp?